# Error 'std::out_of_range' what(): bitset::test in C++ 98

Tags: c++, bitset, c++98

I have taken this code in comment from Question at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72251750/cout-the-unique-values-on-console-stored-in-single-variable) .My objective is to store the unique values stored in single variable `parameter`

```
std::bitset<270> mem; 
void getValue(int parameter)
{
if (!mem.test(parameter)) 
{ 
mem.set(parameter);
 std::cout << parameter << std::endl;
 }
}
```

Above code is giving me this error

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
> what():  bitset::test

**Edit**

This function called from main

```
void main()
{
   int parameter = 0;
    std::cout << "Random numbers :" << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 270; i++)
    {
        parameter = rand() % 270;
        std::cout << "parameter=" << parameter << "\n";
        getValue(parameter);
    }   

}
```

Kindly help me to resolve thi error ?

Comment: The error means that `parameter` is out of range, so it's either < 0 or >= 270. Without knowing where it came from, we cannot help you further.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://wandbox.org/permlink/FvBUEpmd0JaYck9E.  And you surely don't mean C++98.

Comment: I am working in C++ 98 .Can't shift to advance version !!.

Comment: `getValue(int parameter);` ?!? Is this really the code that causes a runtime error? Looks like a typo

Comment: yes `bitset` that is used in `void getValue(int parameter)` is giving that error!!

Comment: It is giving me the output at output at the last index the program crashed giving me the above  error?

Comment: `getValue(int parameter);` is not a function call. The code you posted does not compile, hence not cause a runtime error https://godbolt.org/z/bG6q4GKnW

Comment: and after fixing the typo I cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/hEh43v1bW. It would be good if you could show an example that does not rely on `rand()`. If you can get the error with `rand()` then you can also get it without, but not vice versa

Comment: calling `getValue(i)` should pass all values you can possibly get from `rand() % 270` but that runs fine as well https://godbolt.org/z/9b8TGT7Tf

Comment: please post a [mcve]. A complete example that others can copy and paste and compile to see the same issue as you see.

Comment: Sorry it was typo .I have fixed it !! Program compile and run and displays the output. But program crashed at executing and displaying last index .Kindly help me to fix it ??

Comment: Just a wild guess… Could it be that in some ancient, non-conforming compiler, `rand()` would return `-1` as a sign to indicate that `srand()` was never called to initialize the RNG? Then, of course, `(-1) % 270` would result in `-1`, which would be out of range.

Comment: no i have hard coded some  values without using rand() the error is still the same

Comment: OT: `void main()` is illegal.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a _debugger_ to find out the program state at the moment of throwing exception.

Comment: what does `std::cout << "parameter=" << parameter << "\n";` print before it crashes?